# (python 3.3) using urllib request to read url and open the SAME page on browser (not refreshed one)

Tags: python, url, sudoku

I try to read sudoku through a url and want to openthe same page that contains sudoku I've just read through the url
I am able to read sudokus by reading "show.websudoku.com" url, however when I try to open the same page I've just read, I get a different sudoku than I read in url because the site refreshes sudoku each time. I look some cookie libs but do not understand how to use them. Should I use cookies (and how, in this case) or is there something easier?

```
import urllib.request
import webbrowser

url="http://show.websudoku.com"

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://show.websudoku.com/')

webbrowser.open("http://show.websudoku.com")  ## This page displays different sudoku than print(html)

html = response.read()
print (html)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is such a mechanism on this website to enable fetching the same sudoku over and over again. The decision of which sudoku to send is taken server-side.

One solution to your problem would be to save the output of the first page and access that data over and over again to your liking.

If your goal is only to validate your finished sudoku, you don't need to reload the page, just send the right form values. Get them from the first page, change the necessary fields and issue a POST request.

For this particular site, however, no need to join the server, the answer is included in the page. Look at the field with the id "cheat". It contains all the digits organized by lines. And the field with id "editmask" controls which digit is displayed (0) and which cell should be turned to an editable field (1).

Comment: thanks for the answer, as you said the url already shows the solved sudoku, however I cannot be able to open the webpage on browser that displays 'that specific' sudoku problem. As I understand from your answer, it is not cookie related as well, just not possible to browse the same page. 

But I think there should be a way to do it, otherwise we never get to open the webpage and its url.read because some of the sites changes/refreshes itself on every click